# Not getting getting expected canvas output using canvas draw

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas, cropperjs

https://jsfiddle.net/sumantademon/o93cpLg1/7/

Small Snippet I am attaching here

```
  this.$refs.asdf
                .getContext("2d")
                .drawImage(
                    this.$refs.videoEl,
                    this.cropdata.x,
                    this.cropdata.y,
                    this.cropdata.width,
                    this.cropdata.height,
                    0,
                    0,
                    100, 200
                );
```

Can anybody look into this fiddle and help me to remove the scaling issue in my output and the blocking code.